# My app shows differently in the emulator than in design mode

Tags: android, xml

I'm creating an app which speaks basic French phrases when you click on them. The problem I'm having is that when I run the app on my emulator it does not appear the way it does in the design view in android studio.

[This is how it looks in the design view in android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueGZX.png)

[Now this is how it looks in the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77otz.png)

I'm tried to find the solution to it but so far I haven't come up with anything. the hard part is that in the design preview the app looks the way it should look; that is why even if I make changes to it I won't be able to know how it is gonne effect the look of the app in the emulator.

here is the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.pooria.basicphrasesappstore.MainActivity">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:id="@+id/button0"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:onClick="playPhrase"
            android:tag="0"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="How are you"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:onClick="playPhrase"
            android:tag="1" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="Do You \nSpeak English"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:tag="2"
            android:onClick="playPhrase" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="Good Evening"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:tag="3"
            android:onClick="playPhrase" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="I live In"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:tag="4"
            android:onClick="playPhrase" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="My Name Is"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:tag="5"
            android:onClick="playPhrase" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="Please"
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:tag="6"
            android:onClick="playPhrase" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:text="Welcome"
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:tag="7"
            android:onClick="playPhrase" />

    </GridLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use a different preview device in the layout editor. See if it shows what you see on the emulator

Comment: @Rochezto Delaporana i will check in my android phone it works. please check in another emulator

Comment: And if you remove all the layout gravity's what happens?

Comment: Heights are `wrap_content`. Seems this affects the cells to be like this. Try setting height to 0 and using `layout_weight=1` for each.